# Read Serial port via web browser

Tags: c#, serial-port, modbus, tcomport

I am currently reading Modbus via Serial port (Serial.IO.Ports) using ASP.NET C# Web application, I am able to read the serial port as I am running the application on my local machine.

While working on the project, I thought that the web app won't work once deployed on server because, it will try to access server's Serial port(COM) and not client's (the one running the website) obviously. 
Is there any library or package I can use to read the Serial port of the machine which is running the browser.

Let me know if I was not clear or if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing your app for your customer(s) you can:
1. develop windows-service that accepts http requests 
2. Share the serial somehow on the ethernet so that the server
can connect to the KNOWN ip address.

Browser ( JavaScript ) can't talk directly to the serial port.

Comment: I did something very similar to what you said. Thank you for your response!!  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

You could Try

System.IO.Ports

> Use this class to control a serial port file resource. This class
>   provides synchronous and event-driven I/O, access to pin and break
>   states, and access to serial driver properties. Additionally, the
>   functionality of this class can be wrapped in an internal Stream
>   object, accessible through the BaseStream property, and passed to
>   classes that wrap or use streams.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Serial.IO.Ports will work if running locally. As your link also states it will allow communication between 2 computer connected via null modem cable. What I am trying to do is different. You can check my question again I have edited it a bit.
Thanks!!